# AmForth needs a re-flash after -13 exception (undefined word)

Tags: arduino, atmega, forth

I have an ATMega328p running AmForth 6.1.

While interactively debugging, I accidentally called an undefined word, resulting in AmForth throwing a `-13` exception (`undefined word`).

After the exception is thrown, AmForth acts strange. Calls to pre-defined words such as `words`, or simple operations like `1 1 +` fail.

The only solution I've found thusfar is to re-flash the chip, which is obviously less than ideal.

Am I not handling errors properly? Coming from a GForth background, I am used to just contining operation on exceptions. It seems like AmForth does not operate this way.

How do I get AmForth to behave correctly after calling an undefined word?

Comment: Is it possible to `CATCH` the exception?

Comment: It does look like AmForth's `QUIT` should catch the exception: https://github.com/bewest/amforth/blob/master/core/words/quit.asm, so I guess that shouldn't help.

Comment: Could you show an example of QUIT or CATCH? I tried QUIT, but it's possible that my syntax was off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of using `CATCH` and `THROW`:

```
 \ Throw an exception.
: check    42 throw ;

\ Call check, and catch any exception.
' check catch .
\ Should print 42.
```

I mentioned `QUIT` because it's the default Forth interpreter, and in the [AmForth source code](https://github.com/bewest/amforth/blob/master/core/words/quit.asm), it looks like it should catch exceptions.  Maybe you're using another version of AmForth, or you're not interacting with the standard text interpreter.

`QUIT` just enters the Forth text interpreter.  It may seem a peculiar name, but it makes sense if you call it from a word.  No matter how deep the return stack is, `QUIT` empties it and goes to interactive mode.  It keeps the data stack, however.

```
: foo 1 2 3 quit ;
: bar foo ;
bar .s \ Should print 1 2 3.
```